# Groovy Spread Operator with metaClass

Tags: groovy

Why does this not work?

```
    shareholders*.metaClass.editing = false;
```

But this does?

```
    shareholders.collect{it.metaClass.editing = false}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can't assign multiple values that way in groovy, `[1, 2, 3] = 4` won't work either

and unless you need a list of `false`, you're probably better using `each` instead of `collect`

Comment: I do need a list of false :)